# I need to run a bash command if output has characters and other command if output is empty

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting

I have a mount script and I need to run a command when Python command output has characters in it and if the output is empty then run something else.

Example:

```
## define a function that launched the zenity username dialog
get_username(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Username:"
}
# define a function that launched the zenity password dialog
get_password(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Password:" --hide-text
}

# attempt to get the username and exit if cancel was pressed.
wUsername=$(get_username) || exit

# if the username is empty or matches only whitespace.
while [ "$(expr match "$wUsername" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Error in username!" --text="Please check your username! Username field can not be empty!"  || exit
    wUsername=$(get_username) || exit
done

wPassword=$(get_password) || exit

while [ "$(expr match "$wPassword" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Error in password!" --text="Please check your password! Password field can not be empty!" || exit
    wPassword=$(get_password) || exit
done

Save_pwd=$(python -c "import keyring; keyring.set_password('My namespace', 'wUsername', '$wPassword')")

Get_wPassword=$(python -c "import keyring; keyring.get_password('My namespace', '$wUsername')")

echo $Get_wPassword
# mount windows share to mountpoint
#sudo mount -t cifs //$SERVER/$SHARE ${HOME}/${DIRNAME} -o username=${wUsername},password=${Get_wPassword},domain=${DOMAIN}

# show if mounting was OK or failed
#if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
#       zenity --info --title="Mounting public share succeeded!" --text="Location Documents/Shares/public!"
#else
#       zenity --error --title="Mounting public did not succed!" --text="Please contact system administrator!"
#fi
```

Now in this script I need to run the zenity username input first. Once it's run, the Python **$Get_wPassword** will run, and once it gives an output that is not empty, it will run the `mount` command with the username and password got from **$Get_wPassword**. If the **$Get_wPassword** is empty then I need to run the password input as well with **$Save_pwd** and `mount` command so it saves the password into the keyring and next time the script runs it takes the password from there.

How can I accomplish this? With a **while** loop? If yes, can you give some examples? I am new to scripting.

Comment: That's an intimidating wall of code; are you sure you can't reduce that to an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — different names for the same thing?

Comment: There's just a lot of code there that is not clearly necessary (which is different from 'clearly not necessary'), and it is not clear to me what you're asking.  You just need to remove the extraneous.  For example, the first two loops could probably be replaced by: `wUsername=somebody # Normally got via zenity` and `wPassword=something # Normally got via zenity`.  Some punctuation in your 'Now in this script…' paragraph would probably help, too. I've had a go at improving it.

Comment: You say "I need to run the `zenity` username input first"; that seems to be the first `while` loop.  You then have a loop to get a password, also via `zenity`.  At this point, you have a user name and password; it is then unclear what you want to do next.  The code runs the `Save_pwd=$(python …)` operation; but you describe doing the `Get_wPassword=$(python …)` operation next, which is confusing.

Comment: I want to run zenity user input first so user can input his/hers username then if $Get_wPassword gets a password for that username from keyring via the python command it runs mount command with the password that python command gave. If the python command $Get_wPassword is empty it asks for password from user with zenity and runs $Save_pwd and mount command with the password that user typed in zenity input.

Comment: Update the question, please, rather than adding comments.  I'm still not clear if you want to go back to the start if `Get_wPassword` turns up empty, or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to some command if a shell variable called `Get_wPassword` is non-empty and another command if it is empty.  Fortunately, there is a simple shell test for empty strings:

```
if [ -n "$Get_wPassword" ]
then
    CommandIfNotEmpty
else
    CommandIfEmpty
fi
```

The construction `[ -n somestring ]` returns true if the `somestring` has nonzero length, and returns false if the string is empty.  See `man bash` for more details.

Taking a guess at what you actually want to do, consider:

```
if [ -n "$Get_wPassword" ]
then
    if sudo mount -t cifs //$SERVER/$SHARE ${HOME}/${DIRNAME} -o username=${wUsername},password=${Get_wPassword},domain=${DOMAIN}
    then
        zenity --info --title="Mounting public share succeeded!" --text="Location Documents/Shares/public!"
    else
        zenity --error --title="Mounting public did not succed!" --text="Please contact system administrator!"
    fi
else
    echo "Password was empty..."
fi
```

Comment: So then I can use $Get_wPassword in mount command so it uses the $Get_wPassword output as password as I understand?

Comment: Yes.  After you have run the statement `Get_wPassword=$(python ...)`, the shell variable `Get_wPassword` will be assigned to whatever the output of that python command was.  You can then use `$Get_wPassword` anywhere where that value is required.